# Selenium Clicking on different elements on different computers

Tags: python, selenium

I built a selenium script on my computer at home, On my home computer it works great. I took it into work and it launches the web driver and then it starts clicking on the wrong buttons(if it makes a difference my home computer is a iMac and my work computer is a HP pc). I've double checked the id tags, name tags and I've even selected the path's thru a full xpath. Nothing changes it keeps clicking the buttons next to the correct ones. I've never seen anything like this. Does anyone have any idea what is going on??
I can't post my code so I am sorry about that. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add the code

Comment: ave you check the HTML in both pcs? are they identical? do you use the same browser? It would be good to check. finally add the XPath and the used selenium command you speak about

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. Make sure the browser's zoom level is at 100%

Comment: or check if browsers on both screens have the same resolution.

Comment: Yes, due to different resolutions, the web elements may need to be scrolled into view before they can be interacted with.